# How Do I Resume Music That Is From Outside The App?

Tags: android

I am making a small app and I want for the app to resume playing applications like spotify or pandora once it stops. So, I have this:

```
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    Boolean myChecker = audioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn();

    if(audioManager.isMusicActive() == true)
    {
        Log.i("Hey", "Music Is Playing");
    }
    if(audioManager.isMusicActive() == false){
        Log.i("Hey", "Music Isn't Playing");

        //TODO: Resume The Music My Dudes!

    }
```

I assumed there would be some sort of audioManager function that would resume the background music or play it again, but I haven't found anything that works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

Answer (score 0):

You can call this method

`am.abandonAudioFocus(afChangeListener);` ,

where `afChangeListener` is [OnAudioFocusChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener.html)

> This notifies the system that you no longer require focus and unregisters the 
>       associated OnAudioFocusChangeListener. If you requested transient focus, this 
>       will notify an app that paused or ducked that it may continue playing or 
>       restore its volume.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call onAudioFocusChangeListener to handle all music services.
Like this..

```
  onAudioFocusChangeListener = new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {

        switch (focusChange) {
            case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS):
                break;
            case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT):
                pause();
                break;
            case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN):
                resume();
                break;
            case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK) :
                // Lower the volume while ducking.
                player.setVolume(0.1f, 0.1f);
                break;
        }
    }
};

int mediaresult = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(onAudioFocusChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

if (mediaresult == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
    //other app stop music you can play now
     //put you play code here..
 }
```

Enjoy!!!